# How to Pass array of latitude and longitude from tableview to map view in swift?

Tags: swift

I have tried to pass array of latitude and longitude from tableview to mapview but i unable to implement that so please anyone can help me for implement that.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //let cell:NewTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewTableViewCell

    let cell:MyTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

    cell.citylblTitle.text = recordarray[indexPath.row] as? String

    cell.mapView.description = latitudearray[indexpath.row]



    return cell
}
```

Comment: Post your code please!

Comment: how to use mapview inside the tableview cell